# List files in hierarchy of directory

Tags: shell-script, wildcards, recursive, csh

I need to list files in hierarchy of directory. For that I wrote script like

```
foreach file ( * )
    ls ${file}/*/*/*/*/*.root > ${file}.txt
end
```

But for this I have to know that in the directory ${file} there are 4 directory. So, Is there any way by which I can generalize this script, such that I did not have to be idea how many subdirectories are present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`find`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&sektion=1) command.

```
foreach file ( * )
    find ${file} -name "*.root" > ${file}.txt
end
```

Consider using a shell other than csh, which has been obsolete for about 20 years. Use zsh or bash interactively, and [don't use csh for scripts](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot).

Answer (score 2):

Almost all `csh`s founds these days are actually `tcsh` If you're using tsh 6.18.00 (20120114) or newer, you can use `**` (check with `tcsh --version`):

```
ls "${file}"/**/*.root
```

This will *only* work if the `globstar` variable is set:

```
set globstar
```

Complete docs from `tcsh(1)`:

> The `globstar` shell variable can be set to allow `**` or `***` as a file
>   glob pattern that matches  any  string  of  characters  including  `/`,
>   recursively  traversing any existing sub-directories.  For example, `ls
>   **.c` will list all the .c files in the  current  directory  tree.   If
>   used  by  itself,  it will match zero or more sub-directories (e.g. `ls
>   /usr/include/**/time.h` will  list  any  file  named  `time.h`  in  the
>   /usr/include  directory tree; `ls /usr/include/**time.h` will match any
>   file in the /usr/include directory tree ending  in  `time.h`;  and  `ls
>   /usr/include/**time**.h` will match any .h file with `time` either in a
>   subdirectory name or in the filename itself).  To prevent problems with
>   recursion,  the `**` glob-pattern will not descend into a symbolic link
>   containing a directory.  To override this, use `***` (+)